# Drop Down validations in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have two drop downs with same items. If one item is selected in the first drop down, it should not appear in next drop down.

Comment: Remove the selected value  by reassigning the data to the Second dropdown in the Onchange event of the first dropdown

Comment: It will be better if you share your code what you did.**It should not appear in next dropdownlist**, is that mean if first dropdownlist is selected with some item then that item should not present in second dropdownlist?

Comment: This seems like you have used cascading `DropDownList`. Without this feature, it would not work. Share your code and try to remove the cascading.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: You really should show your code, but you could remove the item either in client side javascript (I think Sami provided an example) or I believe with a server-side binding which can be done in an ASP.NET async block.  I'd go with javascript, especially assuming that you have two drop-downs with identical keys.

Answer (score 0):

[**Working Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/RwiqykIhnSM0XqCStr6X?p=preview)

```
$(function () {

  var lastRemovedIndex = -1;
  var lastRemovedOptionHtml = null;


  $('#ddl1').change(function () {

   if (lastRemovedIndex == -1) 
   {
     //both must have equal(and non-zero) number of children
     if ($(this).children().length < 1 || $(this).children().length != $('#ddl2').children().length)
        return;        
     else 
     {
        //if a has n children then b must have n-1 as 1 child was removed from b
        if ($(this).children().length - 1 != $('#ddl2').children().length)
            return;

  //Little complex. It says add the last removed option at its last position
        if (lastRemovedIndex != $('#ddl2').children().length)
            $('#ddl2').children().eq(lastRemovedIndex).before($(lastRemovedOptionHtml));
        else
            $('#ddl2').append(lastRemovedOptionHtml);
    }
    var objectToBeRemoved = $('#ddl2').children().eq(this.selectedIndex);
    lastRemovedIndex = objectToBeRemoved.index();
    lastRemovedOptionHtml = objectToBeRemoved[0].outerHTML;
    objectToBeRemoved.remove();
  });


});
```